# COnvert number to letter

Tags: python, odoo-8

i had install module **num2words**
this is my code :

```
from num2words import num2words
```

class HrHolidays(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.holidays'

```
interim = fields.Many2one(
    'hr.employee',
    string="Interim")
partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Customer")
remaining_leaves = fields.Integer(compute='_get_remaining_days', string='Leaves')  
number_text=fields.Char(string='Nombre de jour')


@api.multi
def _get_remaining_days(self, name, args):
    res = super(HrHolidays, self)._get_remaining_days(name, args)
    return res

def calculatenumber(self, number_of_days_temp,lang='fr'):
    number_text = num2words(number_of_days_temp,lang)
    return {'value': {'number_text': number_text}}
```

**.xml**

```
             <xpath expr="//field[@name='interim']" position="after">
                      <field name="number_of_days_temp" nolabel="1"  on_change="calculatenumber(number_of_days_temp)"/>

     </xpath>
        <field name="number_of_days_temp" position="after">
            <field name="number_text"/>
        </field>
```

i got this error i dont know how to solve it 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

verify the definition of the function

```
def calculatenumber(self,cr, uid, ids,number_of_days_temp, context=None):
    number_text = num2words(number_of_days_temp,lang='fr')
    return {'value': {'number_text': number_text}}
```

or you can use the new api

```
@api.onchange('number_of_days_temp')
def calculatenumber(self):
    self.number_text = num2words(self.number_of_days_temp,lang='fr')
```

then you must remove  `on_change="calculatenumber(number_of_days_temp)"` from your XML view